# How to read cached request body multiple times in spring-cloud-gateway - the right way

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

When using spring cloud gateway it's possible to cache the request body as `DataBuffer` either by using a global filter or by activating it per route via an `EnableBodyCachingEvent`.

As soon as a Predicate or Filter reads from this `DataBuffer` it's internal read position gets modified. (i.e when using the `DataBuffer::asInputStream`).
Subsequent filters share the same read position as well as the final proxy handler that delegates to an upstream service.

When some stage does not reset the read position to `0`, the upstream http call will fail because either the read position is already at the end and therefor nothing more can be read (which probably results in a timeout error because the http call has a Content-Length defined that can't be read) or the data read is corrupt (wrong position).

A common usecase for us is to implement some kind of schema validation filter.
This requires to read the body, perform a schema validation and in case of success delegate to the upstream.

Our code currently looks something like this:

```java
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(ValidateExchangeConfig config) {
        return (ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) ->
                validateRequest(exchange, config)
                        .doFinally(signalType -> cleanupRequestBodyCache(signalType, exchange))
                        .then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }

    private static void cleanupRequestBodyCache(SignalType signalType, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Optional.<DataBuffer>ofNullable(exchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.CACHED_REQUEST_BODY_ATTR))
                .ifPresent(dataBuffer -> {
                    switch (signalType) {
                        case ON_ERROR -> DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer); // release on validation error
                        // maybe some other cases
                        default -> dataBuffer.readPosition(0);  // reset to allow further processing
                    }
                });
    }
```

Shouldn't there a way to reset the `readPosition` at least as soon as the request is proxied to the upstream service?

So the question is: whats the appropriate way to reset the DataBuffer's readPosition before delegating to an upstream service?

I'm wondering that this - for us very common case - is not addressed somewhere globally.

Comment: Reading the body multiple times is not a common use case we support explicitly.  I would advise reading it once and transforming it once and cache that. The various methods on `ServerWebExchangeUtils.cache*()` are the supported way of caching.